# android, how does FCM knows when and whom the token should be sent

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

For testing FCM, it only needs to create a FirebaseMessagingService and run the app, the token will be passed to it through its onNewToken(String token). (sure need to create a project with FCM console, and download the google-service.json).

The question is how does the FCM know there is an app just start to run and FCM should send the token to it (how)?

the test project has only a mainActivity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
}
```

and a service:

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

  @SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
  @Override
  public void onNewToken(String token) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + token);
  }

  @SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
  @Override
  public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

    //...
  }
}
```

plus added the google-services.json got from the FCM project console. and in respective build.gradle added the apply plugin, following the google FCM site instruction:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
```

and in manifect:

```
        <service android:name="com.demo.mytestfcmnotificationdemo.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually works the other way around: when your app starts, it calls the FCM services and asks them it the token it has is still valid. If it is no longer valid, it gets a new token and then calls this `onNewToken` handler.

So FCM is not actively scanning for tokens that need updating, but waits for the device to reach out and check the status of its token.

Comment: thanks @Frank! but my testing project does not have any code to initiate the call to FCM, it only has a service which is spawned by  FCM (that's the question I have)? I will update my question with project's code.

Comment: When you include FCM in the app, the FCM services request the token. You don't have to include any custom code for that.

Comment: I think this is the part I dont understand.  I register my app with FCM in their project console, and my app has a service waiting to be spawned.  How does FCM knows my app is just started and push the token to it? (After I added the app's package name to the FCM project in its console, it starts to spin a waiting icon, and saying something like waiting for the app to start. After my app starts the spinner stops, and my app received the token). I dont have code in the app to make any call to FCM.

Comment: As said in my answer: FCM doesn't push the token, the FCM code in your app requests it when it starts. This is done by the FCM SDK itself when you include it in your app, so it's not code you wrote.

Comment: thanks @Frank!, I guess it's the the `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`.